# Accessing User Defined Properties in CATIA using VBA code

Tags: vba, catia

I'm looking to access user added properties using code similar to properties that the program auto-generates and using the .selection command to make it work.

The code to access the computer properties is
'''CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Item(1).Value.Name'''

I'm struggling and the best attempt I have towards accessing additional properties fields under the "Product: Added Properties" area:
'''CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.UserRefProperties.Item("Properties\DESIGNER").Value'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, but you have to be careful about the Name of the parameter you give to Item, otherwise, the method fails.
I created a single Product called Product1, where I added a Property MINE :
[image]

Then in VBA I can access the parameter like that :

```
product1.UserRefProperties.Item("Product1\Properties\MINE")
```

[image]